# Why doesn't this Kendo Grid URL map to my controller action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to follow the docs on how to make my kendo mvc grid ajaxified and able to support some in cell editing.

The problem I have is on save, I'm seeing the grid make the following request which is apparently not available. I'm not familiar with the models prefix stuff but it looks like the object is modeled in the URL properly with each property prefixed with &models, then some hash, then the parameter name and then the value.

Why doesn't this URL map to my controller action method?

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - 
http://localhost/MySite/UI/Orders/Update
?models%5B0%5D%5BId%5D=18c12470-0ca3-4e9c-b6d7-af1d6120e03f
&models%5B0%5D%5BNumber%5D=231413+
&models%5B0%5D%5BMod%5D=8ccbf70a-f368-434c-8c05-2e2f5278215d
&models%5B0%5D%5BModName%5D=M6G+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
&models%5B0%5D%5BDescription%5D=M6G+LMU+TTU1200
&models%5B0%5D%5BPart%5D=105442
&models%5B0%5D%5BPartDescription%5D=M6H+TELEMATICS+CONTROL+UNIT
&models%5B0%5D%5BQuantity%5D=20
&models%5B0%5D%5BDeliveryDate%5D=Tue+Apr+30+2013+00%3A00%3A00+GMT-0400+(Eastern+Daylight+Time)&_=1366818145016"
```

The Update method sig in the controller looks like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Update([Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest] Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<Order> order)
        {
        //do update
        }
```

And the sample Order object looks like this

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Number{ get; set; }
    public Guid Mod{ get; set; }
    public string ModName{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Part{ get; set; }
    public string PartDescription { get; set; } // View Model Purposes Only
    [Required]
    [UIHint("QuantityEditor")] //QuantityEditor is the name of the custom editor template
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate{ get; set; }
}
```

Here's the grid code ala MVC:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("my-grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(m => m.Id)
            .Hidden(true)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "some-class" });
        columns.Bound(m => m.Mod)
            .Hidden(true)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "some-class" });
        columns.Bound(m => m.ModName)
            .Hidden(true)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "some-class" });
        columns.Bound(m => m.Description).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "some-class" });
        columns.Bound(m => m.Part).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "part can-edit" });
        columns.Bound(m => m.PartDescription).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "can-edit" });
        columns.Bound(m => m.DeliveryDate).Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "date can-edit" });
        columns.Bound(m => m.Quantity).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "quantity can-edit" }).FooterTemplate("Total:");
    })
    .Scrollable(s => s.Height("auto"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Batch(true)
                    .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Orders"))
                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetAllOrders", "Orders").Data("getAdditionalData"))
                    .Aggregates(aggregates => { aggregates.Add(p => p.Quantity).Sum(); })
                    .Model(model => 
                    {
                        model.Id(m => m.Id);
                        model.Field(m => m.Id).Editable(false);
                        model.Field(m => m.Part).Editable(true);
                        model.Field(m => m.Quantity).Editable(true);
                        model.Field(m => m.DeliveryDate).Editable(true);
                        model.Field(m => m.PartDescription).Editable(true);
                    })
    )

)
```

Comment: can you paste your grid code here. It would be better if we see how your are building your URL in the grid

Comment: @HaBo added grid code. i did manage a workaround using the Save event. I fire off a client side method on save, which gives me a client side object model of the thing that just got updated

Comment: are you sure about , [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<Order> order)? I think it should be  public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Order ordObj)

Comment: @HaBo yeah i would have thought the same, but look at the URL I posted above. each variable in the URL has the models prefix.

Comment: Try some break points around the read and update actions and see which is called and what they display.

Answer (score 0):

At 1st glance it would look like,

```
.Read(read => read.Action("GetAllOrders", "Controller").Data("getAdditionalData"))
```

Instead of Controller you need to put in the actual name of the Controller so for example "PersonController" would be "Person".

Edit- Ok from the looks of it then you've setup your Read from datasource but not your Update and instead tried to do it in events.

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html

I find it easier not to use inline edits and instead create a template button to redirect to an edit page thus keeping the kendo related code simple.

Comment: right, that's just me trying to obfuscate some stuff... i just was meaning to put the word controller as a place holder for the proper controller. let me fix that

Comment: ok, again you're right. i'm not posting this properly. i went ahead and did the update call in ajax by using the Save event to call a javascript method. i've updated my grid to the code that gives the error i'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your grid is being called from within an MVC area.  If you have Areas setup within your MVC application, it's always a good practice to reference those when making calls with Kendo UI Widgets.

Below assumes an Area called "UI":

```
.Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Orders", new { Area = "UI" }))
```